# Merge in Merge Sort Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

I am in the process of learning C++ and I'm trying to instantiate some basic sorting algorithms with it.

This is a sample function for merge, a helper function for Merge Sort provided in some notes of mine.

```
void merge(vector<int> &A, int lo, int mid, int hi)
{
    vector<int> temp;
    int a = lo, b = mid + 1;
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
    {
        if (a <= mid && (b > hi || A[a] < A[b]))
        {
            temp.push_back(A[a++]);
        }
        else
            temp.push_back(A[b++]);
    }
    for (int k = lo; k <= hi; k++)
        A[k] = temp[k - lo];
}
```

1. Can someone explain to me how the first if-statement works? I understand that the conditionals here serve the purpose to ensure that the two pointers don't go out of bound + checking which value is greater between the two sub arrays.

However, I am failing to see a case where a <= mid && b > hi, can someone who knows this sorting algorithm better than me provide me some edge cases where this occurs? Is there a logical equivalent here that someone can provide that will make this if statement more intuitive to me?

2. What is the purpose of the last for loop? I'm assuming it's so that I can return my original array 'A' since I am passing by reference. Is this correct? If so, what is the purpose of setting A[k] = temp[k - lo] rather than A[k] = temp[k]. Since I will be calling merge with lo = 0 inside my actual mergeSort function.

Thanks in advance guys! Apologies for the noob questions.

Comment: I'd run this with a debugger which lets you run the program line by line and allows you to inspect variables. If you don't want to spend 30 minutes or so in learning the basics of your debugger, or if you don't have access to a debugger for whatever strange reason, you can still add output statements at various places that print the contents of relevant variables.

Comment: What happens if the `A[a] < A[b]` branch is taken more than `mid - lo` times? `a` will stay `<= mid` because it never gets incremented, right? What happens if the `[lo,hi]` interval is exactly reverse-sorted? What happens if `mid` isn't exactly half-way between `lo` and `hi`?

Comment: Why you are making your life complicated? This should be easier: `std::vector<int> merge(std::vector<int>& a, std::vector<int>& b).` only two parameters which purpose is obvious.

Comment: Condition explained: `a <= mid` - have elements to copy from first rage? `b > hi` - don't have elements to copy from second range? `A[a] < A[b]` is element of first range smaller the element of second range.